# Is this an example of a functional subtype relationship?

Tags: types, covariance, typing, subtyping, generic-variance

[From this video by *Functional Programming Principles in Scala *"4.5 Variance"**](https://youtu.be/QDzPNv4UIkY?t=223) you can see a slide that says,

[Translated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdf6Y.png):

> Say you have two function types:
>
> ```
> type A = IntSet => NonEmpty
> type B = NonEmtpy => IntSet
> ```
>
> According to the Liskov Substitution Principle, which of the following should be true?
>
> - `A <: B` (checked)
> - `B <: A`
> - `A` and `B` are unrelated.

The video claims type `A` is a subtype of type `B`; but, it does so saying,

> Type A satisfies the same contract as Type B if you give it a NonEmpty set it will give you back an IntSet, **but it will actually satisfy more than B**.

But that's not true, B includes the NonEmpty set which includes **more** than an IntSet. Is this video just straight up incorrect and confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's implied (perhaps mentioned in a previous lesson?) that `NonEmpty` is a subtype of `IntSet`. Based on the way Odersky was speaking, it sounds like `NonEmpty` is the subset of `IntSet`s that are not empty. So `A` accepts more argument values than `B` does, and returns a narrower subset of values than `B` does, a subset with additional properties.

Comment: That would make sense. What a weird example if that's he what he meant it would be a lot clearer to show `IntSet` in terms of a `NonEmptyIntSet` and an `EmptyIntSet` (I guess), rather than in isolation.